# How to run my bash script from any folder

Tags: bash

I am trying to run my bash script from another folder 
I want it to be executed from which folder i want

What should I do ?

Im trying to used find in the beginning but it doesnt work !

```
find /path/to/Files -type d -exec Notes-Khaled-Mustafa.sh {} \;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question that a professional or a programming enthusiast would ask.

Comment: @oguzismail I will reopen that question, because that would be the kind of question I would be thrilled, as a beginner, to find on Stack Overflow. An opportunity to guide and explain. Not judge and dismiss.

Answer (score 2):

`./Notes-Khaled-Mustafa.sh {}` simply path the current folder as a *parameter* to your script.
Which is not what you want. You want to execute your script with, as its current execution folder, the one you list through the `find` command.

That is done by calling a subshell and executing a `cd` in it.

In your bash session, try instead:

```
find . -type d -execdir /path/to/Note-khaled-mustafa.sh \;
```

So not "`./Note-khaled-mustafa.sh`", but "`/absolute/full/path/to/Note-khaled-mustafa.sh`"

This uses `-execdir` to [change directory to each matched path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108216/7490). If your version of `find` doesn't have `-execdir`, use instead:

```
 find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "$1" && /path/to/Note-khaled-mustafa.sh' sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to run the script and you do know the name, try

```
/path/to/Notes-Khaled-Mustafa.sh
```

if this does not work, change the permissions:

```
chmod +x /path/to/Notes-Khaled-Mustafa.sh
/path/to/Notes-Khaled-Mustafa.sh
```

Comment: It doesnt work ! Im trying to run the bash script om git and i want to executed just by ./Note-khaled-mustafa.sh enter. Deoesnt matter where im standing if in the same flder or not

Comment: Do you have a shebang in the file on the first line, like #!/usr/bin/env bash? if not, try directly bash /path/to/Notes-Khaled-Mustafa.sh

Comment: If the script does not specify what it is, it cannot just run.